# What is FirebaseApp?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I was implementing Firebase Storage in my app and in the documentation it mentioned initializing the Firebase Storage instance with a custom FirebaseApp, I was wondering what that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has its core package that initiates as a client app, this is often referred to as "FirebaseApp" for clarity reasons. This app instance also maintains a name to differentiate it from others since it is possible to manage multiple instances for different firebase projects.

When you initiate Firebase, it will ask for credentials to the project to connect to including its services endpoints for storage, firestore, and real-time database.

Comment: and what is firebaseapp.com web-site?

Comment: that's a page redirect for convenience. don't mix app naming conventions as a substitute for a website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean custom Firebase App instance.
It is just an added layer of security if you want to authenticate every new user that is logging in to your firebase enabled app.

Ref:https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#use_a_custom_firebase_app